# Processing very large images as numpy arrays

Tags: python, image, numpy, large-data, numpy-memmap

I am dealing with images greater than 8 GB in .svs format. Using openslide, I have read them as 1D numpy arrays. Now in order to feed them into an algorithm I need to reshape them into image form for processing the pixel location related information. 
Since the images are very large, using PIL to convert numpy array as

```
image=np.load('test.npy') 
im=Image.fromarray(image)
```

is throwing  me an error `size does not fit in int`. I tried to workaround this error by changing the `dtype` from `uint8` to `uint64` but, my python keeps on crashing despite having `64GB RAM and 3 TB memory` on my workstation.

Then I tried to load numpy array using `memmap`:

```
    im = np.load(curr_path)
    shapeIm=im[:].shape  ##shape of the image
    name_no_ext = os.path.splitext(f[i])[0]
    filename=path.join(dir,name_no_ext+'.tif') ##filename to save the image file
    #Create a memmap with dtype and shape that matches our data:
    fp = np.memmap(filename, dtype='uint8', mode='w+',shape=shapeIm)  #memmap to read/write very large image files in chunks directly from disk
    #Write data to memmap array:
    fp[:] = im[:]
    fp.filename == path.abspath(filename)
    #Deletion flushes memory changes to disk before removing the object:
    del fp
    #Load the memmap and verify data was stored:
    newfp = np.memmap(filename, dtype='uint8', mode='r+', shape=shapeIm)
```

Now the above code is giving me an image in `.tif` format. But, I cannot process it. I couldn't analyse why? I found that when I tried to read that image and print its shape.

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'

So, This way also failed for me.  Then I tried reshaping numpy array in the shape of the image which is (44331, 64625, 3), and I got the following error

> ValueError: sequence too large; cannot be greater than 32

Can anyone help me how to process such image. I have annotations of these images in x,y,z pixel locations and to process these annotations as ground truth, I need to convert my numpy array in the form an image.

Any help would be great.

Edit: I got reshaping numpy array working now. But, still do not know how to use numpy files as my dataset input instead of images.

Comment: I just tried to load, save and reshape a `np.uint8` array of that size on a far less capable machine (`16GB`) and it works flawlessly. Why do you need to convert it to a `PIL.Image`? Can't you work with pure numpy arrays?

Comment: I am still learning python and I need to conform my dataset according to the particular algorithm which takes images as input. I am though trying to workaround and use numpy arrays instead of images as my dataset.

Comment: Could you outline what kind of processing you want to do? I work with 50gb+ SVS images using pyvips, perhaps that could work for you.

Comment: I want to read the images and predict a bounding box around a tumour region. I have ground truth annotation files in xml format. If I am going for block processing then I have to change my annotation files accordingly, And I want to avoid that.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand in enough detail what you need. If you know the bounding box in pixels of the area you want to analyze, you could efficiently extract those pixels as a smaller image for processing in numpy. Would that solve your problem?